# Powershell EWS. Получить список писем из определённой папки почтового ящика и скопировать иди переместить в другой ящик

Tags: powershell, exchange, ews

Стоит задача раз в день пересылать полученные за сутки письма из определённой папки почтового ящика (Имя папки не стандартное и создаётся пользователем) и копировать\перемещать в папку другого почтового ящика (имя папки так же не стандартное).

Если использовать такой код:

```
# Создание фильтра для поиска писем в указанной папке и за указанный период
$filter = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsGreaterThan([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::DateTimeReceived, $startDate)
# Создание объекта определяющее количество элементов на странице предварительного просмотра.
$view = New-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(1000)

$filterEndDate = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsLessThanOrEqualTo]::new([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::DateTimeReceived, $endDate)



$SourceFolderView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1) 
$SourceFolderView.Traversal = [Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.FolderTraversal]::Deep
$SourceSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName, $sourceFolder) 
$SourceFindFolderResultsID = $service.FindFolders([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot, $SourceSearchFilter, $SourceFolderView) 

$items = $service.FindItems($SourceFindFolderResultsID.id, $filter, $view)



$items | Where-Object { $_.DateTimeReceived -le $endDate } | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Copy($destinationMailbox)
}
```

то поиск осуществляется по почтовому ящику пользователя, под которым происходит авторизация  в EWS, а требуется по любому другому, на который есть права.

Так же не не удаётся разобраться как указать папку почтового ящика, куда нужно копировать\перемещать письма.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для подключения к другому ящику можно использовать следующее:

```
$mailbox = mailbox@domain.ru

$Service = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService]::new()
$Service.ImpersonatedUserId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $MailboxName)
$Service.AutodiscoverUrl($MailboxName,{$true})
```

А для поиска нужной папки следующее:

```
$FolderName = 'Some Folder'

$FolderView = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(99999)
$FolderView.PropertySet = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$FolderView.Traversal = [Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.FolderTraversal]::Deep
$FindFolders = $Service.FindFolders([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot, $FolderView)
$Folder = $FindFolders| Where-Object {$_.Displayname -eq $FolderName}
```